# How does the interactive PHP shell work?

Tags: php, console

I am in the interactive shell for PHP using the command `php -a` in a terminal, but no commands are working. I even try a simple `2 * 2`, and I get no results.

What am I doing wrong and how does it work?

Comment: Try `echo 2*2` instead. Is there anything from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) that is specifically not working?

Comment: @Garry Cairns echo doesnt return anything either I dont get it

Comment: What's your OS and php version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On [the documentation for the interactive shell](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php), the first note by Ryan P. has some notable information:

> Interactive Shell and Interactive Mode are not the same thing, despite the similar names and functionality.
>
> If you type `php -a` and get a response of 'Interactive Shell' followed by a `php>` prompt, you have interactive shell available (PHP was compiled with readline support). If instead you get a response of 'Interactive mode enabled', you DO NOT have interactive shell available and this article does not apply to you.

So if you get only "Interactive mode enabled", then you'll only be able to type in PHP code and then when you're done, send PHP an EOF to execute it.

This is probably not what you want. You may want to look into [phpsh](http://phpsh.org/) instead.

Comment: Since php 5.6 you can use [phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com/) as awesome php interactive shell with debugger integrated in php core!

Comment: How do I send an "EOF"?

Comment: @KolobCanyon: On most UNIX-like systems, by pressing control-D. On Windows, by pressing control-Z.

Answer (score 15):

### How to use the PHP interactive shell

The `php -a` has less features than phpsh.

*[phpsh](https://github.com/facebookarchive/phpsh)* was made by Facebook.

Install Git, and go to where you want to build *phpsh*:

```
sudo apt-get install git
cd /home/youruser;
```

Pull the repository, [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) into it and install:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/phpsh
cd phpsh
sudo python setup.py install
```

Run it:

```
phpsh
```

Output:

```
Starting php
type 'h' or 'help' to see instructions & features
php>
```

Assign Hour into a variable and print:

```
php> $t = date("H");

php> echo $t;

04
```

Everyone loves *if* statements:

```
php> if (false){echo "derp"; } else if(true){ echo "foobar"; } else{echo "moo"; }
foobar
```

Get the length of a string:

```
php> echo strlen("012345678");

9
```

Sorting:

```
php> $numbers=array(4,6,2,22,11);
php> sort($numbers);
php> echo $numbers;
Array

php> print_r($numbers);
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 22
)
```

Sort by keys:

```
php> $age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
php> ksort($age);

php> print_r($age);

Array
(
    [Ben] => 37
    [Joe] => 43
    [Peter] => 35
)
```

Push values onto a stack and pop them off.

```
php> $a[]="one"
php> $a[]="two"

php> print_r($a);

Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
)

php> echo array_pop($a);
two

php> echo array_pop($a);
one

php> echo array_pop($a);
```

Basename gets the word on the right:

```
php> echo basename("http://foobar/helicase");
helicase

php> echo basename("/home/el/polymerase");
polymerase
```

Touch a file and get the last time it was modified:

```
php> touch("/home/el/myfile.txt");

php> echo filemtime("/home/el/myfile.txt");

1386494608
```

Love me some JSON:

```
php> $myjson = '{"a":1}';

php> var_dump(json_decode($myjson));

object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

There are several ways to grab something from inside JSON content:

```
php> $json = '{"foobar": 123}';

php> $obj = json_decode($json);

php> print $obj->foobar;
123

php> print $obj->{'foobar'};
123
```

Function, JSON validator

```
php> function isJson($string) {
 ...  json_decode($string);
 ...  return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
 ... }

php> echo isJson("");
1

php> echo isJson("{}");
1

php> echo isJson("abc");

php> echo isJson("{'a': 1}");

php> echo isJson('{"a": 1}');
1
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you (gracefully) exit phpsh?

Comment: Re *"The php -a you speak of is a piece of crap."*: Can you be more specific? What is wrong with it?

Comment: @PeterMortensen More specific: 2013 me engaging in the identity politics of software.   If I had to give a 2023 account, I'd say that 2013 brain stem was treating these complex objects as if they were members of troop needing correction in retaliation for irritation.  The Borg hivemind no longer tolerates such emotion.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have PHP 5.1.0 compiled with `--with-readline`?

> As of PHP 5.1.0, the CLI SAPI provides an interactive shell using the
>   -a option if PHP is compiled with the --with-readline option.

The example from the PHP manual page:

> $ php -a
>
> Interactive shell
>
> php > echo 5+8;
>
> 13

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Answer (score 1):

Are you using print() or echo()? Your example of 2*2 will execute, but you won't see any proof of it until you tell PHP to do something with the output like print().

```
php -a
php > 2 * 2;            #This doesn't return anything.
php > print (2 * 2);
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you end each command with a semi-colon.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer (and not downvoted). Matt Grannary is indeed correct - "`2 + 2`" alone does not do it - it should be "`2 + 2`;" and then the output will be `4`.

Comment: Though it seems it is very sensitive to spaces. What is the explanation? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22262935/edit) some example input and output? (But ************** ***without*** ************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: For example, in a `php -a` session , "`echo(2+2);`" results in "`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in php shell code on line 2`". From the command line, this outputs the expected "`4`": `php -r 'echo(2+2);'`. (Both on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) and PHP 7.2.24.)