# How to execute in PHP interactive mode

Tags: php, command-line

I am new to PHP, and I just wanted to run PHP in a command prompt (interactive mode).

So I typed this code:

```
`php -v`
`<?php`
`echo 7;`
`?>`
```

But I do not know how to execute it, because when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> cmd expects me to continue writing the code. I searched on php.net and some other forums, but I didn't find anything. So is there a function key or something to display the result?

Comment: I also tried doing that. The answer is in the first code from the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php)
In a nutshell, you have to compile php with --with-readline option. The comment also says that you input php -m and see if there is readline in it. On windows machines, there is none.

Comment: This is #2 in a search engine hit for "`site:stackoverflow.com php interactive session`". The short answer is "`php -a`".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will trigger an end-of-file condition and cause the script to be executed.

See also *[How does the interactive PHP shell work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792842/how-does-the-interactive-php-shell-work)*:

> > Interactive Shell and Interactive Mode are not the same thing, despite
> > the similar names and functionality.
> >
> > If you type php -a and get a response of 'Interactive Shell' followed by a php> prompt, you have interactive shell available (PHP
> > was compiled with readline support). If instead you get a response of
> > 'Interactive mode enabled', you DO NOT have interactive shell
> > available and this article does not apply to you.
>
> So if you get only "Interactive mode enabled", then you'll only be
> able to type in PHP code and then when you're done, send PHP an EOF to
> execute it.

"EOF" means "end-of-file".

Comment: No such character as EOF. EOT (end of transmission) is sent with Ctrl + D; ETX (end of text) is sent with Ctrl + C. [More.](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm)

Answer (score 29):

If following your command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> isn't working, you probably don't have `Interactive Shell` (which apparently gives input after each line). That requires compiling `php` with special options. But if `php -a` says `interactive mode`, you can type directly into it and send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> at the end of the file.

```
php -a
interactive mode enabled

<?php
echo "hello there world!";
phpinfo();
?>
^Z
```

(Hit <kbd>enter</kbd>)

```
hello there world!
phpinfo....
```

There's more information in the comments in the [PHP comments](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#105729).

Comment: What OS are you using? Ctrl+Z immediately exits using Linux Mint

Comment: @kurdtpage `CTRL`+`Z` should suspend, not exit. Trying running `jobs`, `bg`, and `fg`.