# syntax error, unexpected (T_VARIABLE) in php shell code

Tags: php, syntax-error

I wrote a simple function to execute in php interactive way:

```
php -a
php > function mytest()  {
php {     $tmpstr='yyy'; 
php {     $tmpstr=$tmpstr."xxxx";
php {     echo $tmpstr;
php { }
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$tmpstr' (T_VARIABLE) in php shell code on line 3
```

The source code:

```
function mytest()  {
    $tmpstr='yyy'; 
    $tmpstr=$tmpstr."xxxx";
    echo $tmpstr;
}
```

I can't find what is wrong with this simple function.

[image]

Comment: the code is correct. using your code in my `php -a` doesn't produce the syntax error you show.  I'd assume that you inserted (i.e. copy-pasted) your code from somewhere that contains "invisible" characters or some unicode `;` or whatever which screws parsing. try copying the sourcecode from your own question and pasting it into `php -a` to verify

Comment: theres a difference between interactiv shell and interactiv mode, wich do u use ? maybe that helps :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391811/how-to-execute-in-php-interactive-mode